# Graph algorithm to recurrently partition graph into chunks with 0 input edges

Tags: graph-theory

I've got a problem (and I guess solution) to the following problem:

Given a dependancy (directed) graph of some tasks (i.e. you need to run task 1,2 before 3 - 1 and 2 are vertices with edges going into 3) split it into vertice groups which can be run in parallel.

So basically all needs to be done is to:

1. Get all vertices with 0 edges going into them
2. Remove them from the graph, add them to a group
3. Go to 1. for the graph without those vertices or stop if there's none

And considering this seems like a pretty common problem I was wondering is there a name for this algorithm in graph theory?

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen this algorithm, but by the description you make of it, I would describe it as a greedy [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) in a directed acyclic graph.

It is very similar to the [Coffman Graham algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffman%E2%80%93Graham_algorithm), without being exactly the same; in their algorithm, vertices are being labeled one at a time, not in groups, and they select them in lexicographic order to guarantee the uniqueness of the solution. It seems easier to implement their version of the algorithm, since it only requires to label vertices in the graph, without having to maintain a list of sets and removing vertices/edges from the graph.

Note: the graph has to be acyclic (usually, scheduling graphs have to be, or we'd be confronted to the chicken/egg problem) to guarantee that the algorithm terminates.